# How can I access a Properties.Settings.Default property if I have its name as a string?

Tags: c#

I have a number of properties in `Properties.Settings.Default` whose name all start with `"store"` and an integer number, these numbers follow in sequence and what I would like to do after the method is fired off is to increase the number in the property name, i.e. from `"store1"` to `"store2"`.

I keep getting an "identifier expected" error. I'm rather new at programming, so any help would be appreciated.

```
public void store()
{
    storename1.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
    if (File.Exists(Filedestination))
    {
        File.Delete(Filedestination);
    }
    NumberOfScales = Properties.Settings.Default.("store"+ Convert.ToString(storeNumber) + "NrOfScales");
    StartRange = EndRange - Properties.Settings.Default.DegrendelNrOfScales;
    IPRange = Properties.Settings.Default.DegrendelIPRange;
    CurrentRange = StartRange;
    PingScales();
}
```

I don't even know how I can read a property with the name `("store" + Convert.ToString(storeNumber) + "NrOfScales")`. If I knew how to do that, it would shorten the code by at least 9/10ths as I would not have to redo this for every single instance of all the stores that I have. Is there any way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, it seems like you possibly chose the wrong place to store your data. Is there any particular reason why you are using Windows Forms' [*application settings*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx) (`Settings`) to store data?

If you really want to do it that way, IIRC **you can access a setting by its name using `Properties.Settings.Default["PropertyName"]`** (where you can substitute `"PropertyName"` by any expression that yields a string, e.g. `"store" + Convert.ToString(storeNumber) + "NrOfScales"` (or more succinctly in Visual Studio 2015 or later, `$"store{storeNumber}NrOfScales"`). You will get back an `object` that you'll have to cast to whatever type of values you stored in there, e.g.:

```
var numberOfScales = (int)Properties.Settings.Default[$"store{storeNumber:D}NrOfScales"];
```

---

Some hints about syntax used here:

- The `[]` syntax is called an ["indexer"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).
- `$"…"` is for [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). It often allows for neater concatenation of strings than by using `+`.
- The [`D` (decimal) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString) used in `$"…{…:D}…"` makes sure that `storeNumber` will be formatted as a decimal without any thousands/decimal separators.

Now, back to my initial question, if you're open to other means of storing data, let me point out a few alternatives:

- If you only need the data during one single execution of your program, i.e. the data does not need to be persisted from one run of the program to the next, then a [`Dictionary<string, int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) might be sufficient. Dictionaries allow you to associate `int` values with `string` values and look them up by these `string`s.
- If your data is actually user content / business data, then don't store it as "application settings". At the least, store the data to a simple file (possibly to [Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx)) using the facilities under `System.IO` (`File.Create`, `File.Open`, `StreamWriter`, etc.). If you want to store structured data, you could make use of relational databases (see e.g. SQLite, SQL Server Compact, or SQL Server) or document databases.
- If the data you're storing is in fact data that influences the setup / configuration of your application, then your current use of application settings might be fine.

Comment: thank you so much you have no idea how much this helped me, i originally though that saving it in system memory was "lighter than using a database, but saving the info to ping 600+ units in the settings proved to be more of a headache than a database